# Ajax.ActionLink in MVC3 appears to act the same as HTML.ActionLink

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an ASP.Net MVC page where I want to use AJAX to update a child table of the parent table the user is editing/viewing on the form. I'm sure this is a very standard pattern but as I'm new to the platform.

In my page I have the following:

```
  <ul id="see_also_list">
  <!-- this part is in a partial -->
    @if (0 < Model.RelatedCategories.Count)
    {
        foreach (string cat in Model.RelatedCategories.Keys)
        {
            <li>@Html.ActionLink(cat, "Details", new { id = Model.RelatedCategories[cat] }) 
            [@Ajax.ActionLink("remove", "RemoveSeeAlso", new { id=Model.Id, RelatedCategory = Model.RelatedCategories[cat] }, new AjaxOptions{ Confirm = "This will remove this item", HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "see_also_list" })]</li>
        }
    }
    else
    {
        <li>No related Categories listed.</li>
    }
  <!-- end of partial -->
  </ul>
  @using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddSeeAlso", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "see_also_list",   InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
  {
      @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
      @Html.DropDownList("alsoCategories", Model.LoadCategoryDropdown())
      <input type="submit" value="Add" />
  }
```

The problem I have is that both the Ajax form and the Ajax.ActionLink appear to be behaving in the same way as HTML.ActionLink - they are navigating the browser straight to the action on the form. When the link to the "Confirm" AjaxOption enabled, it doesn't show any kind of confirm box. I guess that I am missing some critical piece of plumbing required for this to work or that the built in helper methods don't help as much as I hoped they would and I need to add a bit of extra JavaScript manually.

The HTML created by the Ajax.ActionLink looks like this:

```
<ul id="see_also_list">

        <li><a href="/Category/Details/2">Advice and Information                            </a> 
        [<a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-confirm="This will remove this item" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#see_also_list" href="/Category/RemoveSeeAlso/1?RelatedCategory=2">remove</a>]</li>

</ul>
```

I am including "jquery.validate.min.js", "jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js", "MicrosoftAjax.debug.js" and "MicrosoftMVCAjax.debug.js".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're missing the link to the jquery unobtrusive library (usually linked in your _Layout page)

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Without this, no one will handle the `data-ajax` and the other ajax-related attributes

Comment: Perfect, that was precisely the problem.